# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\{x\} \ln x^n}{[x]}$

Tags: limits

Here, $\{.\}$ represents fractional part function and $[.]$ represent integral part function

Can I get a hint to get me started, because I have no idea how to begin. Not the complete answer, just a hint.

Comment: start by convincing yourself whether or not it should exist

Comment: squeeze theorem

Comment: "No idea" most likely means that you won't understand the answer.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I do not understand how you got that.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong. I guess it tends to $0$ by the squeeze theorem like you said.

Comment: The hint is that $0\le \{x\} \lt 1$ and $[x] \gt x-1$.

Comment: @Tavish good hint!

Answer (score 4):

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\{x\} \ln x^n}{[x]}$

This thing looks scary, but it's surprisingly easy.

I'll assume $n>0.$

I'm not going to spoon-feed you the answer, and I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you're new to these two terms "fractional part" and "integral part".

I also haven't heard these terms before, but they're easy to understand.

The "fractional part" (also called the "decimal part") of $123.79$ is $0.79$.

The "integral part" ("integer part") of $123.79$ is $123$.

So for large $x$, the fractional part $\{x\}$ is between $0$ and $1$. But the integral part $[x]$ is large (a large integer).

Also, I'll wager that you're capable of simplifying $\ln(x^n)$.
$$$$
OP, get your spoon out. For every *nonnegative integer* $n$, we have all of the following:

For all $x>1, x^n\geq1,\ $ so $\ln x^n\ $ is positive.

Furthermore, for all $x,\ $ $0 \leq \{x\} < 1,\ $ and $\ 0< x-1 < [x].\ $ Therefore:

$$\forall x>1:\quad 0<\frac{\{x\} \ln x^n}{[x]} < \frac{1 \times \ln x^n}{x-1} = n\ \frac{\ln x}{x-1},\ $$ and

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(n\ \frac{\ln x}{x-1}\right) = n \times \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\right) \overset{\mathrm{(*)}}{=} n \times \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}\right)\ = n \times \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ = n \times 0 = 0,$$

where [L'hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) was used at $(*).$

Therefore, by the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), $\ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\{x\} \ln x^n}{[x]}\right) = 0.$

$$$$
Finally, for negative integers $-n,\ (n >0),\  \large{\frac{\{x\} \ln x^{-n}}{[x]} =  -n \frac{\{x\} \ln x}{[x]}},\ $ and so $$\ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\{x\} \ln x^{-n}}{[x]}\right) = -n \times \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\{x\} \ln x}{[x]}\right) = -n\times 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Simplifying $\ln (x^n)=n\ln x$? I don’t how that helps here. Do u mean the expansion of It?

Comment: Also I am very familiar with those terms, but I do have trouble evaluating them when they appear before me

Comment: $0 \leq \{x\} < 1$, so you're basically just computing $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a n \ln x}{x}$, where $n$ is a constant and $0 \leq a < 1$. When you take the limit, it doesn't matter where $a$ is between $0$ and $1$. Now I'm spoon-feeding you though...

Comment: I would really appreciate being spoon fed since I have no idea what you mean to say. There is no standard limit for $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}$ and there is no way to substitute $n$. I see that there can be no answer other than 0 when no values are given, but I would still like to understand it

Comment: " I see that there can be no answer other than $0$ when no values are given" what do you even mean by this?

Comment: Updated my answer for some delicious spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 1):

As others already stated, you have to reason on the meaning of the two functions. Assuming $n > 0$,

$$\{x\} \in [0, 1)$$
$$[x] \geq 1\ \text{for}\ x \geq 1 $$

Using the log property $\log(x^n) = n\log(x)$ your limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{n\{x\}\log(x)}{[x]}$$

Since $\text{max}\big(f(x) = \{x\}\Big) = 0.\bar{9}$ and the integer part is not bounded from above, (or more rigorously: $[x] = x - \{x\}$ hence $[x] \leq x - \{x\}$) the limit can be estimated as

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{n\{x\}\log(x)}{[x]} \geq \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{0.\bar{9}n\log(x)}{x - \{x\}} \geq 0.\bar{9} n \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{\log(x)}{x-1} = 0$$

Where the very last result is obtained, for example, via De L'Hôpital rule.

*Caveat*

We all do know that $0.\bar{9} = 1$, but, well... you know... It's for the sake of an estimation.